# VHDL Sensitivity List

Tags: vhdl

I need to complete the sensitivy list of the following question, can somebody help me out?

```
signal:A,B,C,X,Y,Z:bit
comb1:process (  ....  )
begin
X<=Z xor B;
Y<= X or B;
C<= A and B;
Z<=A;
B<= not Z;
end process;
```

Do I need to include all the signals ?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.3 Process statement para 6 "For each assignment statement, apply the rule of 10.2 to each expression occurring in the assignment, including any expressions occurring in the index names or slice names in the target, and construct the union of the resulting sets." 10.2 Wait statement para 3 "A simple name that denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set." Targets of assignment  are simple names here (10.5.2.1) not simple expressions (9.1). ***Do I need to include all the signals ?*** No. One or more signals don't appear in expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to VHDL-2008, this is trivial:

```
signal:A,B,C,X,Y,Z:bit
comb1:process (all)
begin
X<=Z xor B;
Y<= X or B;
C<= A and B;
Z<=A;
B<= not Z;
end process;
```

The VHDL-2008 keyword `all` includes all signals read in a process in the sensitivity list automatically, and is much easier to maintain than an explicit list.